# Return Rx value not available when passed into Angular ForEach

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs

I subscribed to a Rx return and pass that to Angular.ForEach loop **but it has value undefined**. However, I manage to get the result on console.log print.

Below is the calling typescript code

```
this.wordPressBlogPostRepository.getPortfolios().subscribe(
    (result) => {
        this.stopLoading();
        this.viewmodels = result;
        console.log(this.viewmodels);
        angular.forEach(this.viewmodels, function (value, key) {
            this.viewmodels[key].title.rendered = value.title.rendered.replace("Softinn Portfolios: ", "");
        });
    },
    (error) => {
        swal({
            title: 'Error',
            text: error,
            type: "error"
        });
        this.stopLoading();
    }
);
```

Below is the error message:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewmodels' of undefined
    at AngularControllers?v=rVYJl6CURXT7t6FM4ZFRtRuO0C-mN9uPa6W1ArXQ9301:1
    at Object.t [as forEach]

It works if I do this instead

```
this.wordPressBlogPostRepository.getPortfolios().subscribe(
    (result) => {
        this.stopLoading();
        this.viewmodels = result;
        console.log(this.viewmodels);
        for (var blogCounter = 0; blogCounter < this.viewmodels.length; blogCounter++) {
            this.viewmodels[blogCounter].title.rendered = this.viewmodels[blogCounter].title.rendered.replace("Portfolios: ", "");
        }
    },
    (error) => {
        swal({
            title: 'Error',
            text: error,
            type: "error"
        });
        this.stopLoading();
    }
);
```

**What did i miss? Should I use (complete) instead of (result)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely because of the context of `this` within your `forEach` function.

You can try:

```
angular.forEach(this.viewmodels, (value, key) => {
            this.viewmodels[key].title.rendered = value.title.rendered.replace("Softinn Portfolios: ", "");
        });
```

As the fat arrow functions maintain the context of `this`